# how can i change the hover to click funtion for below code?

Tags: jquery, html, css

in this code i could not modify to click function.when over the mouse on the window the overlay animation working and same like this animation function will working when i click on the window. can anyone help me. my code is bellow.

```js
var $animation_elements = $('.animation-element');
var $window = $(window);

function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

  $.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
      (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
      $element.addClass('in-view');
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('in-view');
    }
  });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content-item {
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* height: 300px;*/
  height: 998px;
  /* height:auto;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  /*width: 400px;*/
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}
.content-item .overlay {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: .95;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  width: 0;
}
.content-item:hover .overlay {
  border-bottom: 2700px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 2700px solid transparent;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
/*.overlay_CLICKanim {
 border-bottom: 2600px solid #e8c63d;
    border-left: 2600px solid transparent;

  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}*/

.content-item .corner-overlay-content {
  bottom: 15px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.content-item:hover .corner-overlay-content {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
/*.corner-overlay-content_anim {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}*/

.content-item .overlay-content {
  bottom: 0;
  color: #333;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.content-item .overlay-content h2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 0 0 12px;
}
.content-item:hover .overlay-content {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
/*.overlay-content_anim {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}*/

/*animation element*/

.animation-element {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0% 1.33 2.66% 1.33%;
  float: left;
}
/*3 grid layout*/

.animation-element:nth-of-type(3n-2) {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0% 1.375% 2.75% 0%;
  clear: left;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
}
.animation-element:nth-of-type(3n-1) {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0% 1.375% 2.75% 1.375%;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
}
.animation-element:nth-of-type(3n-0) {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0% 0% 2.75% 1.375%;
  clear: right;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
}
.bounce-up .subject {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 700ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 700ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 700ms ease-out;
  transition: all 700ms ease-out;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 200px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 200px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 200px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 200px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 200, 0px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* transform: translate3d(0px, 571.061px, 0px); opacity: 0.681153;
  -moz-transition: all 700ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 700ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 700ms ease-out;
  transition: all 700ms ease-out;*/
}
.bounce-up.in-view .subject {
  opacity: 0.5;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 74px;
  padding: 40px;
}
a {
  color: #292727;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul:active {
  opacity: 1 !iimportant;
}
.parent_header {
  position: relative;
}
.main {
  /*position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
  z-index: 9999; */
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.blue {
  /* background-color:transparent;*/
  /*display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: -102%;
    transition: .4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: .4s ease-out;*/
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.main {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: .4s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: .4s ease-out;
}
.closebtn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;position: relative;top: 50%;left: 5%;z-index: 9999;opacity: 1 !important;color: aliceblue;" class="menu_bar">&#9776;</span>
  <div class="content-item">

    <div class="overlay"></div>

    <div class="corner-overlay-content">Info</div>

    <div class="overlay-content">
      <div class="container cf">
        <ul class="animation-element bounce-up cf">
          <li class="subject development active">
            <a href="">HOME</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="animation-element bounce-up cf">
          <li class="subject development">
            <a href="">ABOUT US</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="animation-element bounce-up cf">
          <li class="subject development">
            <a href="">PORTFOLIO</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="animation-element bounce-up cf">
          <li class="subject development">
            <a href="">GALLERY</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need click event on the screen ,if not then you can disable the click event on the screen then it will work only on hover and please try to reduce you code here else it will be to understand for other.

Comment: @Tanmay i removed click event..